# Exported path not updating in Python

Tags: python, bash, path

I am using `os.environ` to include a path using

```
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + bin_path
```

In the `bin_path`, there is a executable `ping`. However, doing a `shutil.which(ping)` shows that `ping` has been picked up from a different location. How to enforce that `ping` accessed is the one from `bin_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is searched in order. If you want your directory to take precedence, you need to put it at the beginning, not the end.

```
os.environ['PATH'] = bin_path + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
```